# Cassandra UDF and user input

Tags: cassandra, cql, udf

I am using Cassandra 2.2 and I'm having a problem with User Defined Functions.

I want to create a function that take as parameter a integer column of a table and another integer as user input and mutiply the two values as follow:

> CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION testFunc (val int, input int)
>
> CALLED ON NULL INPUT RETURNS int
>
> LANGUAGE java AS 'return val * input;';

I can execute the function on two integer column like

> select testFunc(int_column, another_int_column) from my_table;

and it's working, but when I try to execute it with a user input like:

> select testFunc(int_column, 3) from my_table;

i receive following exception:

> SyntaxException: ErrorMessage code=2000 [Syntax error in CQL query] message="line 1:22 no viable alternative at input '3' (select testFunc(year, [3]...)"

Is it possible to achieve what I'm trying or I should find another way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling, UDF in this way `testFunc(int_column, 3)` is same as passing an `int` to a function parameter which takes `String` (i.e column name) only and hence the incorrect syntax error `no viable alternative at input '3'`. Not sure if this fits into your scenario, but you can try something like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION testFunc (val int)

CALLED ON NULL INPUT RETURNS int

LANGUAGE java AS 'return val * 3;';
```

Or add a `multiplier` column to your table.

Comment: thanks for your answer, I was looking for something that can change at every call, like calling the funcion once to multiply by 3, once to multiply by 5 and so on depending on user needs without having to write a function for every case.

Comment: In that case( i.e variable multiplier) handle it on application level. I don't think CQL provides any such facility. If you want SPARK-SQL may work in this scenario.